# How won't time decrease by 1?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I have a value that I want to decrease by 1 every second then format into the datetime format so it looks like the timer is counting down. My problem is that every second it returns the same value and not decrease by 1.

```js
var measuredTime = new Date(null);

var number = 180;

var timeFormat = measuredTime.setSeconds(number);

console.log("test");

setInterval(function () {
 timeFormat = timeFormat - 1; 
 var timeString = measuredTime.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
 console.log(timeString);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Change `timeFormat = timeFormat - 1;` to `number -= 1; measuredTime.setSeconds(number)` inside the callback. Does this fix the issue? Also note: `setSeconds` requires the input to be at most `59`... so it will give random results with `number = 180` but should work with `number = 59`

Comment: `measuredTime` is never updated so the console log outputs the same every time.

Comment: @GACy20 , yes that has worked. But what if I have an input that's more than 59? Like 180?

Comment: `new Date(null)` is equivalent to `new Date(0)`, just less efficient, less obvious and more to type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overcomplicated that quite a bit. You're never updating `measuredTime` so it shows the same thing every time.

This should do it:

```js
var number = 180;

setInterval(function () {
 var time = new Date(number * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)
 console.log(time);
 number--
}, 1000);
```